# materialize sass form_for rails file_field

Tags: ruby-on-rails, carrierwave, cloudinary, materialize

Trying to get Materialise sass to work with a rails partial form (I was originally using simple_form however now I just want to get it working on a new form)

I'm using carrierwave & cloudinary - uploading works fine however when I want to theme the upload buttons with the classes from Materialise - it seems to override the button and gives me a choose file labelled button over my materialise theme button (so it does pass the class).

code below

```
    <%= form_for @post do |f| %>

<%= f.cl_image_upload(:picture, :html => { :class => "btn" }  )  %>

<%= f.submit  %>

<% end %>
```

Comment: I'm guessing it pulls in a jquery api?

Comment: nevermind found a solution

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
  <div class="#">
         <div class="file-field input-field gallery_picture">

        <div class="btn">

          <span>Upload file</span>
          <%= f.input_field :picture %>
          </div>
        <input class="file-path validate" type="text"/>
        </div>

    </div>
```